# The web application at <> could not be found sharepoint 2013.

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

The web application at <> could not be found  sharepoint 2013. 
If the url should be serving exisitng content, the system administrator may need to add a new request url mapping to the intended application

I search stack exchange but didn't get answer that suit my scenario

Problem: Console application accessing SP 2013 site, using server side object model.
Console application would be schedule on production server. When executed manually it runs normal. When the same application is schedule in task schedular it fails and give error i mention in the begining.

Schedular is running in the same user context which is used for runing exe from command prompt.

What is already checked:
Mode is 64 bit
AAM is fine
User under which it should run, its in wss group on WFE.

Any pointer will be appreciated

Comment: Does the Task have "Run with highest privileges" set?

Comment: Do you mean run with elevate prevliage? No it is not runing with run with elevate. After you comment i tried, but result is same